# Does squaring an absolute value binomial of norms remove the absolute value?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Does $ | (\|x\| - \|y\| )|^2 = (\|x||-\|y||)^2$?

I'm solving a question and I used this step but wasn't sure if it was valid.

Comment: Yes since a (real) square is always nonnegative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from 
$$
(a-b)^2=\bigl((-1)\cdot(b-a)\bigr)^2=(-1)^2\cdot(b-a)^2=(1)\cdot(b-a)^2=(b-a)^2
$$